# Can't disable GNOME Shell hotspot / hot corner / Activities "feature"

Tags: desktop-environment, gnome-shell, user-interface

I have a Fedora 21 box set up with the latest GNOME Desktop.  I would like to completely disable the hotspot / hot corner / Activities or whatever it is called.  I have read that using the `Applications Menu` GNOME shell extension (enabled via `gnome-tweak-tool`) will do the trick, but it does not (though it does properly disaply a classic applications menu).

I've also read that you can force the disabling of it by manually modifying this file:

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/layout.js
```

but that file is not on my system.

```
$ rpm -qv gnome-shell gnome-session
gnome-shell-3.14.4-2.fc21.x86_64
gnome-session-3.14.0-1.fc21.x86_64
```

One other note - not sure if it matters - I am choosing the GNOME Classic session when logging in, versus the default GNOME Desktop.

I have found no other alternative solutions to try.

Comment: Shell files now come as a binary. Try https://extensions.gnome.org/

Comment: @don, i'm not sure what your comment or suggestion mean.  Went to the website (been there already), nothing for me to do there.  The applications menu extension is already on my system.

Comment: so if you search for "hot corner" on that site you don't get any results ? like, extensions that deactivate it ?

Comment: @don, ah, okay. i did not search for "hot corner" before - i was only looking for "application menu".  i did find some hot corner links on that website, so i'll try them on Monday and update...thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Go to extensions.gnome.org and install the extension [No Topleft Hot Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/).